# Mac OS package installer fails to install a simple test app

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I'm trying to figure an issue with building an install package for a Mac OS application. It's a simple hello world app and I use `pkgbuild` to do so.

If I simply package my app with no pre/post install scripts, the app installs fine. However, as soon as I add a preinstall script that does nothing but an echo, the installation fails with no meaningful message:

> The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

This is the command that creates a successful install:

```
pkgbuild --component HelloMac.app --install-location /Applications  HelloMac${VERSION}.pkg
```

And this is the one that creates a pkg file that fails:

```
pkgbuild --component HelloMac.app --install-location /Applications --scripts scripts HelloMac${VERSION}.pkg
```

I have only one file called `preinstall` in the scripts folder and it has one line `echo "hello"`

How can I debug this failure? Or what else am I missing? Does the package need to be signed to run the scripts (mine is not)?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect the preinstall script doesn't have a valid stdout, so `echo` gets an error trying to send output to... well, nowhere, causing the script to exit with an error status, so Installer interprets that as meaning installation cannot proceed.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I just replaced the `echo` with `exit 0` and I'm getting the same results,

Comment: In that case... I don't know what the problem might be. Is there anything in the installer log?

Comment: Where does the installer log things? I checked the console application for system logs and couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the the Bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
exit 0
```